# Is there any log of login attempts to sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, authentication

Where can I find a log of login attempts to share point 2007?

Thanks.

PS: I have another question too, I 'd be really grateful if anybody helps me on it:
[Sharepoint users are logged out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992182/sharepoint-users-are-logged-out)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find much without a third party tool.  Our group is looking into acquiring DocAve by [AvePoint](http://www.avepoint.com).

In the mean time you can at least get an idea in your site analytics area of your site settings dashboard to see how many people have encountered the /_layouts/accessdenied.aspx page.  It wont tell you much, but perhaps you can find a way to customize and add a snippet of code that will take a user's ID when they hit that page.  Its not perfect, so I'd suggest a 3rd party tool unless you can scan all of your web front ends etc.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement once, where we needed to log the last visited time of all the users on the site. So after some period of time, say 90 days, if a particular user had not logged into the site, the admin could delete his profile.

We overcame this problem with a very simple approach. You can follow the sample code for your reference.

You would need to create a list in your site by the name "UserLoginDetails" and create a column "LastLogIn" in that. Code is self explanatory.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace Ubaid.WebParts
{
[Guid("883a77d6-271d-4b88-9ca2-d5150a00520b")]
[DefaultProperty("Text"), ToolboxData("<{0}:UserLastVisited runat=server></{0}:UserLastVisited>"), XmlRoot(Namespace = "Ubaid.WebParts")]
public class UserLastVisited : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        string siteName = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteName))
        {
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            SPList UserLoginDetailsList = web.Lists["UserLoginDetails"];

            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            string uname = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + uname + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
            SPListItemCollection listItemColl = UserLoginDetailsList.GetItems(query);

            if (listItemColl.Count > 0)
            {
                SPListItem item = listItemColl[0];
                item["LastLogIn"] = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
                item.Update();
            }
            else
            {
                SPListItem item = UserLoginDetailsList.Items.Add();
                item["Title"] = uname;
                item["LastLogIn"] = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
                item.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

You can insert this webpart in your masterpage, as the data in this list needs to be updated on every page load.

Not sure which is the best way to do it / performance issues, but since ours was a small site we could manage with this pretty well.